# Rendering Multiple PayPal Payment Buttons on a Page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal JS SDK payment buttons where all you do is copy the code into your HTML site and the PayPal buttons appear to initiate a checkout.

This works for only one button on the page, but I have 3 subscriptions a user can choose from (daily, weekly, monthly)

If I copy the code into my daily div area it works correctly, but then if I copy the code into the weekly div it wont appear and only the daily div PayPal button appears. But if I remove the code from the daily div the button will appear under the weekly div.

It seems I can only use button code once?

I tried modifying the code by changing the id name and function names but still no luck.

Is there a way to have multiple PayPal on my page?

Here is the [generated code](https://www.paypal.com/buttons) from PayPal:

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=test&currency=AUD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"daily","amount":{"currency_code":"AUD","value":1}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
<br><br><br>
<p> gefwdsa</p>
<div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=AUD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"weekly sub","amount":{"currency_code":"AUD","value":5}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

This only makes the first button appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SDK script,

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=AUD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
```

Should only be loaded exactly once per page, above all the buttons.

Additionally, each button must render to a div with a unique HTML `id`, so this line:

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

And this line:

```js
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Both need some corresponding different/additional string suffix for each button, e.g. paypal-button-container-1 , -2 for the next buttons' etc.

---

Also client-id of `test` or `sb` is sandbox mode, you need a live client-id from the 'Live' section of an app in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications

2023 update: actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used in any new integration. All buttons should (when clicked) create and capture orders using server backend routes that are fetched