# Multiple PayPal Buttons on One Page

Tags: paypal

I am trying to add multiple PayPal buttons to my sales page for the same product. The idea is that as the customer scrolls, they reach several different places where they could check out.

For example, if the customer reaches Checkout Point #1 and decides not to purchase, he/she can keep scrolling down the sales page to get more information on the product. Eventually the customer will reach Chekout Point #2 where they will again be presented with the buttons to purchase. The product and price are the same at every checkout point.

I found my checkout code by going to Pay & Get Paid > PayPal Checkout > Get Started > Choose a Ready to Go Option. I copied the code provided to me on that page and added it to my website. Right now, only my first button is working when I embed the code from PayPal. The PayPal buttons do not appear at any of the other three checkout points.

I need to have four checkout points - two on the desktop version of my site and two on the mobile version. I don't know if the first code is cancelling out the other three or how to fix it. Can somebody please help me figure out how what"m doing wrong? I'm not the best tech person! Thank you very much!

Comment: Here is the code

Comment: Where is it? Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64961093/2069605

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is that snip of code

Comment: Hi @PrestonPHX. For some reason I didn't have luck with that answer. I'm not sure how to send you the code. The code is over the character limits for the comment box.

Comment: Update your question and use markup syntax